# select multiple image from gridview and display in other activity

Tags: android, eclipse, gridview, android-intent

I am creating Gallery. I have grid view which display all images. Now i want to do that when we select multiple images using check box then another intent will start that i have done,but now i want to display that selected image in this new intent.

thanx in advance.

Comment: Well can't you save checked positions of images in bundle if the are in some sort of list and than display them in new activity ?

Comment: i am new to this platform can u pls give some example...

Comment: Paste some code so that we can help you, we need to see where are you stuck

Comment: i have used the below link.....in this i m getting count but i want to pass seleted image from one activity to another......http://vikaskanani.wordpress.com/2011/07/20/android-custom-image-gallery-with-checkbox-in-grid-to-select-multiple/          thanks

Comment: @user960439 [here](http://www.technotalkative.com/android-select-multiple-photos-from-gallery/) is the improved version of that article.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically what you want is on button click to start new activity instead of toast and then display the selected images, right ?

Check the line 72 :`selectImages = selectImages + arrPath[i] + "|";`

This is path to image and the i is the position you want to save somehow because this way you will know which images are selected. You can save it as a List,or Array for example and then on button click start new Activity,pass this List or Array in bundle and in new Activity fetch
the image ids and look for images in Bitmap array thumbnails[imageID]. You will need to change
visibility of

`private Bitmap[] thumbnails;`

to public. Try it and let us know if you have success, if not we can help you further ;)

**EDIT**
Here is some more help, pass int array in bundle

```
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
    intent.putIntegerArrayListExtra("arr", pics);//pics is your array with id-s of bitmaps
    startActivity(myIntent);
```

You will add that instead of toast in onClick of your button and read it in next Activity with:

```
Intent i = getIntent();  
integer [] fromApics = i.getIntegerArrayListExtra("arr");
```

**EDIT 2**

Ok Ill write some code for you but read it and try to understand it:
In your main activity change this:

```
selectBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            final int len = thumbnailsselection.length;
            int cnt = 0;
            String selectImages = "";
            ArrayList<Integer> pics=new ArrayList(thumbnailsselection.length);
            for (int i =0; i<len; i++)
            {
                if (thumbnailsselection[i]){
                    pics.add(i);
                    cnt++;
                    selectImages = selectImages + arrPath[i] + "|";

                }
            }
            if (cnt == 0){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Please select at least one image",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "You've selected Total " + cnt + " image(s).",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.d("SelectedImages", selectImages);
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(AndroidCustomGalleryActivity.this, Test.class);
                 myIntent.putIntegerArrayListExtra("arr", pics);//pics is your array with id-s of bitmaps
                startActivity(myIntent);
            }
        }
    });
```

Also set on top of page visibility of:

```
public static String[] arrPath;
```

Create new Activity called Test that looks like this :

```
package com.isummation.customgallery;
```

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

```
public class Test extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Intent i = getIntent();  
    ArrayList<Integer> fromApics = i.getIntegerArrayListExtra("arr");
    for(int y=0;y<fromApics.size();y++){
        System.out.println(AndroidCustomGalleryActivity.arrPath[fromApics.get(y)].toString());
    }

}
```

}

Don't forget to add activity in manifest file also and you will be able to see printed image paths in logcat. Thats it I leave it to you to customise Test activity and make a gallery of selected images or whatever

Comment: sry to say this.....can you pls give me exact code bcoz i m very new to java......i can understand wt you said above but dont knw hw to implement in code.....pls help

Comment: Intent i = getIntent();  
    ArrayList<Integer> fromApics = i.getIntegerArrayListExtra("arr");
    for(int y=0;y<fromApics.size();y++){
        //getting error like source not found in printin .....System.out.println(AndroidCustomGalleryActivity.arrPath[fromApics.get(y)].toString());
    }

Comment: 12-06 12:47:22.572: E/AndroidRuntime(304): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-06 12:47:22.572: E/AndroidRuntime(304): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.pml.imirror/com.pml.imirror.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-06 12:47:22.572: E/AndroidRuntime(304):at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)12-06 12:47:22.572: E/AndroidRuntime(304):at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
12-06 12:47:22.572: E/AndroidRuntime(304):at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)

Comment: Make sure you changed your code like I did in my post, I don't know how to start chat here because it would be easier than to write comments here

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20679/discussion-between-user960439-and-vodich)